# Combine Hydrodynamics and Electromagnetics

Tags: finite-difference, simulation, electromagnetism

Is it possible, in general, to combine hydrodynamical motion and expansion of material with, say, a finite difference time domain method to simulate light-matter interaction?

If so, how is this done in practice? I guess you would need some kind of operator splitting scheme. If you know more about it, can you suggest me some papers, textbooks, etc.?

Comment: There's a large body of work on this under the name *electrohydrodynamics*, as well as on the even more popular *magnetohydrodynamics* (MHD, which describes, e.g., plasma flow).

Comment: thanks, that's already helpful. Do you happen to know if there's a library out there which can handle electrokinetics? I was only able to find a bunch of 'static' maxwell-solvers

Comment: I'm not familiar with any, and I'd be surprised if you found a ready-made, one-size-fits-all solver for such a challenging problem.

Comment: On the other hand, it's certainly possible to implement such a solver using libraries such as deal.II or FEniCS, but I'll leave that to the experts to address.

Comment: Apologies for another non-answer, but in addition to EHD and MHD, another keyword that may help your search is *radiation hydrodynamics* or "rad-hydro."

Comment: No problem, Any keyword might help. I've also found "opto-thermo" and "opto-electro-thermal" modeling to be helpful. It seems like for some length/time-scales static/quasi-static approximations are appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding simulation:
There are several commercial solvers that might be helpful.

- A very popular FDTD Maxwell equation solvers for nanophotonics is [Lumerical](https://www.lumerical.com/tcad-products/fdtd/). It features opto-thermal and *liquid crystal* (which I would say is another keyword you should consider) simulations that should be very relevant.
- Another go-to multiphysics solver would be COMSOL. Searching for *electrohydrodynamics* and *magnetohydrodynamics* will results in a lot of results. Several relevant papers for COMSOL-based modeling:

  1. M. G. Sailer, B. J. Kirby, "[Computational simulation of electrohydrodynamic systems pertaining to micro and nano scale fluid flow phenomenon](https://www.comsol.com/paper/computational-simulation-of-electrohydrodynamic-systems-pertaining-to-micro-and--5400)," in *Proc. COMSOL Conf.*, Boston, MA, 2008.
  2. A. Mulye, S. Potnis, "[Electrohydrodynamic micropump modeling for
     performance optimization](https://www.comsol.com/paper/electrohydrodynamic-micropump-modeling-for-performance-optimization-15883)," in *Proc. COMSOL Conf.*, Bangalore, India, 2013.
  3. N. Kleinknecht, "[High frequency magnetohydrodynamic calculations in COMSOL](https://www.comsol.com/paper/high-frequency-magnetohydrodynamic-calculations-in-comsol-10670)," in *Proc. COMSOL Conf.*, Stuttgart, Germany, 2011.
  4. Y. Yan, S. Smolentsev, M. Abdou, "[Validation of COMSOL multiphysics for magnetohydrodynamics (MHD) flows in fusion applications](https://www.comsol.com/paper/validation-of-comsol-multiphysics-for-magnetohydrodynamics-mhd-flows-in-fusion-a-50552)," in *Proc. COMSOL Conf.*, Boston, MA, 2017.

Regarding numerical techniques themselves:

- I recently stumbled upon the following paper (that was my main motivation even to write an answer to your question): E. Veerapaneni, "[Integral equation methods for vesicle electrohydrodynamics in three dimensions](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcp.2016.08.052)," *J. Comp. Phys.*, vol. 326, pp. 278-289, Dec. 2016. From its abstract: *The method uses a semi-implicit time-stepping scheme to overcome the numerical stiffness associated with the governing equations.*
- And another paper that crossed my eyes several years ago that features numerical study in magnetohydrodynamics: M. Kinet, B. Knaepen, and S. Molokov, "[Instabilities and transition in magnetohydrodynamic flows in ducts with electrically conducting walls](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.154501)," *Phys. Rev. Lett.*, vol. 103, 154501, Oct. 2009.